# Adding a Random Symbol to a Password in C

Tags: c

So as of now this program outputs a password with 5 Uppercase Char, 5 Lowercase Char and 2 Numbers.. but I also want to add a random symbol too from a list like !£$%^&*()+=<>?/@
Can I add it in a for loop like the numbers and characters?

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE*fp; 

int main(void) {

char password[5 + 5 + 2 + 1];
int i, j=0, len=sizeof(password)-1;
int menuNum = 0;


fp = fopen("passwords.txt", "a+"); 
//Opens the text file to save the Passwords

srand(time(NULL));
printf("       Main Menu\n");
printf("********************************\n");
printf("\nEnter 1 to Generate a New Password: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 2 to Check Old Passwords: ");
printf("\n\n");
printf("Enter 3 to Exit. ");
printf("\n\n");
scanf("%d", &menuNum); // reads number

if (menuNum == 1)
{
    printf("********************************\n");
    printf("\nYour New Password is: \n\n");

//Each Password will Have 13 Characters(5 Upper, 5 Lower, 2 Numbers & 1 Symbol)

for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'a' + rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1); //Generates 5 random Lowercase characters 

for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    password[j++] = 'A' + rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1); //Generates 5 random Uppercase characters

for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    password[j++] = '0' + rand() % ('0' - '9' + 1); //Generates 2 random numbers

password[j] = '\0';
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(password)-1; ++i)
    {
    char c = password[i];
    j = rand() % len;
    password[i] = password[j];
    password[j] = c;
    }

printf("%s\n\n", password);
printf("********************************\n");
fprintf(fp, "\n%s", password); //Outputs the Generated Passoword to the text file
fclose(fp); //Closes the text file
system("pause");
}
```

}

Comment: Create an array of those symbols and generate a random number within the array's range.

Comment: `£` might be problematic to use with `char`

Comment: So If I add an array like: char symbols [] = {"!$%^&*()_+=@#~><?"}; Before main...

Comment: been told to maybe use an ascii table, not sure if that would make it more difficult or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
char *special_stuff = "!$%^&*()+=<>?/@";

...
password[j++] = special_stuff[rand() % strlen(special_stuff)];
```

(I removed the `£` character because it might create all sorts of problems for you, e.g. being multibyte-encoded).